# Unit test failed don't know why

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js

This is my original code:

```
email: function ( val ) {
    if ( !val || !/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test( val ) ) {
        return [ 'BAD_EMAIL' ];
    }
```

This is the unit test:

```
describe( '#email', function () {

    it('should fail invalid emails', function () {
        expect( Validators.email( 'test.com' ) ).to.be([ 'BAD_EMAIL' ]);    
    });
} );
```

I don't understand why this failed? I got this error: `expected [ 'BAD_EMAIL' ] to equal [ 'BAD_EMAIL' ].`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array is not equal to array as they are not primitive values in JavaSscript. Change `to.be` to `to.equal`